# Is there a package for easy integration of the Google Contacts API or the Facebook Multi-Friend Selector?

Tags: meteor

I'm new with Meteor (and Javascript and Node.js too, actually) and working from the Parties example. It's amazing how smooth it is to integrate logins with Facebook, Google , Twitter, etc.

I also want to allow users to easily invite people by selecting them from their existing address book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no package specifically built for integration with either of those two services; however, if you're using the baked-in accounts package you can request permissions for extended user information during login.

For either Facebook or Google, you can specify `requestPermissions` either using [direct login](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithexternalservice) or with the [bolted on `{{loginButtons}}` helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_ui_config). In the latter case, you config the `requestPermissions` like so:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    facebook: ['user_likes'],
    github: ['user', 'repo']
  },
  ...
});
```

Per the docs, you can get a list of Google permissions [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#scopeparameter), and Facebook permissions [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

It looks like Google allows access to their basic profile; Facebook has [extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) that authorize reading the user's friend list.